# printing pairs from a list in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, mit-scheme

I'm trying to print pairs from one list kinda like a subset in scheme but with two elements just like this

(1  2  3  4  5)

((1 2)  (1 3)  (1 4)  (1 5)  (2 3)  (2 4)  (2 5)  (3 4)  (3 5)  (4 5))

the code I wrote doesn't work

```
(define (subset x) 
(if ( null? x) x
    (map cons x (subset (cdr x)))))
```

this just return an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to write the lambdas explicitly, makes it easier to understand what arguments are passed:

```
(define subset
    (lambda (lst)
        (if (null? lst)
            lst
            (append (map (lambda (el) (cons (car lst) el)) (cdr lst))
                    (subset (cdr lst)))
        )))
```

---

```
(subset '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> ((1 . 2) (1 . 3) (1 . 4) (1 . 5) (2 . 3) (2 . 4) (2 . 5) (3 . 4) (3 . 5) (4 . 5))
```

---

**EDIT:** The explanation about map below is only valid in some versions of scheme, read Sylwester's comment to this answer.

[map](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Mapping-of-Lists.html) traverses n lists supplied to it and applies `proc` to the n elements in the same position in the lists. This means it can apply `proc` no more times than the length of the shortest list, but you keep giving it an empty list (from the last recursive call backwards).

(BTW this is in plain `scheme`)

Comment: You information about `map` is inaccurate. According to both R5RS and R6RS if there are more than one list argument to `map` they **must** have the same length. [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) works the way you describe and the R7RS-small seem to have adopted it as well although not many implementations support R7RS yet.

Comment: @Sylwester thanks for the comment, I'll edit my answer. I figured that was the case when debugging OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

In `#lang racket` that is very easy since we have `combinations`:

```
(combinations '(1 2 3 4 5) 2)
; ==> ((1 2) (1 3) (2 3) (1 4) (2 4) (3 4) (1 5) (2 5) (3 5) (4 5))
```

Now this does not print anything. To get it print to the terminal you can use `displayln`:

```
(displayln (combinations '(1 2 3 4 5) 2))
; ==> #<void>, ((1 2) (1 3) (2 3) (1 4) (2 4) (3 4) (1 5) (2 5) (3 5) (4 5)) printed to terminal as side effect
```

Answer (score 0):

If order of items is also important, following can be used:

```
(define (subsets l)
  (let loop ((n 0)                     ; run a loop for each item
             (ol '()))                 ; start with blank output list
    (cond
      [(= n (length l)) (reverse ol)]  ; output ol when last item reached; 
      [else 
       (let* ((x (list-ref l n))       ; get one item
              (jl (for/list ((i l)     ; get remaining list
                             (j (in-naturals))
                             #:unless (= j n))
                    i))
              (kl (for/list ((i jl))   ; make combinations with each of remaining list
                    (list x i))))
         (loop (add1 n) (cons kl ol)))])))
```

Testing:

```
(subsets '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Output:

```
'(((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5))
  ((2 1) (2 3) (2 4) (2 5))
  ((3 1) (3 2) (3 4) (3 5))
  ((4 1) (4 2) (4 3) (4 5))
  ((5 1) (5 2) (5 3) (5 4)))
```